# Rails Device and has_many association with promotions privilege

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, associations, destroy

I have two models User and Promotion, an user can create has_many promotion and an promotion belong to user,
for the users i used **devise** so:

**when I delete a promotion, I would like that the users can't delete also the promotions of other users but only their own**

I have to change the controller but how? i hope in a help

this is controller for the destroy of a promotion

```
def destroy
@promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])
@promotion.destroy
#@promotion = current_user.promotions.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to promotions_url, notice:'Promotion was successfully delete.' }
  format.json { head :ok }
 end
 end
end
```

sorry for my english please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crosscheck if the `current_user` is also the creator of the `@promotion`:

```
def destroy
  @promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])
  if @promotion.user == current_user #if user is the owner of that promotion
    @promotion.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to promotions_url, notice:'Promotion was successfully delete.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: i have an other similar problem , i have also model Goods and Promotions, an goods  has_many promotions and an promotion belong a good , so i would that Users delete only the  goods associated with the promotions them have created. Do you have an idea?

Comment: `@good.promotion.user == current_user`. Or, if you correctly set-up [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association), then, you can simply do - `@good.user == current_user` check.

Comment: `def destroy
    @good = Good.find(params[:id])
    if @good.promotion.user == current_user
    @good.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to goods_url, notice:'Goods was successfully delete.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
    else
     redirect_to goods_url ,:notice => 'This is not your good.'
    end
  end
  end
` in this way i have this error 
**NoMethodError in GoodsController#destroy** undefined method `promotion' for #<Good:0x4701fa8> app/controllers/goods_controller.rb:79:in `destroy'

Comment: and used has_many: through association
NoMethodError in GoodsController#destroy
undefined method `user' for #<Good:0x341ca60>

models are:

user.rb
`  has_many :promotions ,:foreign_key => "user_id",
      :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :goods, :through => :promotions`

promotion.rb

`belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :good
`
good.rb
`belongs_to :category
  has_many :promotions    , :foreign_key => "good_id" ,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :promotions`